# Can pynput mouse know if shape of pointer is a 'hand'?

Tags: python, mouse, pynput

I have created a script where the mouse clicks at random positions at the screen.

The only issue is that if there is already something at that position, then clicking on that location is not allowed.

We must click on a location where there is no one there.

This can easily be distinguished by the cursor type.

If the cursor is the arrow, then it is a free position. If the cursor is a hand, then there is already someone there.

After setting the mouse position, is there a way to know if the cursor is an arrow or a hand?

The code doesn't matter here since I am asking more for documentation knowledge, but if you must see:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as mc

mouse = mc()

mouse.position = (xPos,yPos)

mouse.press(Button.left)

mouse.release(Button.left)
```

[image]

Comment: I think it couldn't.

Answer (score 4):

In windows,you could use `win32` to do it, a minimal example. By test, I found it is normal cursor when the `info[1]` is `0`, and it will be the hand cursor when `info[1]` is `6`:

```
import win32gui
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    e = win32gui.GetIconInfo(win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1])) # GetCursorInfo()[1] to get "HCURSOR",GetIconInfo to get the info about the cursor.
    # print(e)
    if e[1] == 0:
        print("Now it is normal")
    if e[1] == 6:
        print("It is hand")
```

---

Official document in MSDN:
[GetIconInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-geticoninfo),[GetCursorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorinfo)